# Can I link an xml file to an xsl file that is not saved in the same directory?

Tags: xml, xslt

Just a quick question.

In all the tutorials I've seen about xml/xslt, the xsl file is always saved in the same directory as the xml file. My question is; can I have an xml file that links to an xsl file that is saved somewhere else and have it linked via a url?

What I'm specifically trying to do is have an xml file and an xsl file saved in a Dropbox folder and link the xml file to the xsl file with a url.

It would look like this;

xslt file would be the usual;

```
<?xml version= "1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version= "1.0"
xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

And xml file;

```
<?xml version= "1.0"?>
<?xsl-stylesheet type= "text/xsl" href= "http://dl.dropbox.co...ame_of_file.xsl"?>
```

I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work but I wasn't sure if that had something to do with it being in a Dropbox folder or if both documents absolutely have to be in saved in the same folder in the same directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect client-side XSLT to work that way then check the error console of the browser you are trying to use that approach with, it is likely telling you that an XML document from one origin is not allowed to load a stylesheet from a different origin. If that is no the case then you need to tell us more details as to how you are trying to run the XSLT transformation.